# Filling and submitting textarea with Mechanize in Python

Tags: python, mechanize

Okay, so I'm using Mechanize to log into Google groups and manually add a member to the group.

I've been able to successfully log in and navigate to the appropriate page. On this page there is a textarea box where you can add the e-mail addresses you want to manually add to the group.

Here is the html for the textarea:

```
<textarea class="gwt-TextArea GFBTXDWBA-" id="gwt-uid-224" aria-haspopup="false" dir="" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-activedescendant=""></textarea>
```

When I run a loop:

```
for form in br.forms():
print form
```

The only form that gets returned is the 'Search members' form at the top, none of the text areas appear.

I don't think select_form is going to work because it's not actually a form.  There is an 'Add' button on the top left of the screen that submits the input from the textarea here is the HTML for the 'Add' button:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
```

What **I'm trying to do** is add an e-mail address to the text area and submit it.  Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Here is my full code:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

r = br.open('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fd%2Fmanagemembers%2Ftesttgroup123456%2Fadd&hl=en&service=groups2&passive=true')
html = r.read()

br.select_form(nr=0)

br.form['Email']='myUsername'
br.form['Passwd']='myPassword'
br.submit()

for form in br.forms():
    print form
```

Comment: I take it https://developers.google.com/google-apps/groups-settings/ isn't suitable for some reason?

Comment: @Jon, I'm unfamiliar with the API, is it possible to do what I'm trying to do with it?  If so, would you be kind enough to point me in the right direction, I've looked through the documentation and I'm unable to find something that looks like it would accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Umm - I can't say I have experience of it, and it looks a bit unwieldy, but it's probably meant to be the preferred approach - http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fsamples%2Fgroupssettings

Comment: Thank you, but going through this I still only see options for modifying group permissions and settings, not adding members to the group.  I'll dig a little deeper though to make sure.

Comment: Okay - its looks quite ambigious whether there's an official preferred way of doing this - which seems a bit of a flaw on Google's side... and some of it depends on provisioning - so I may have wasted your time here -  sorry!

Comment: @Jon, no it's not a problem.  I did find a pretty useful page because of your suggestion: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#creating_a_user_account, has options for python, php, etc... my only issue with this is,  for this project, I don't want to assign passwords to each user (this is one of the arguments for adding a new user)... instead I just want to add an e-mail address as you can on the actual groups webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach to this is to use Google's Provisioning API

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/